# yii 2 Добавление скроллинга или масштабирование на странице

Tags: php, html, css, веб-программирование, yii2

На странице у меня обычный crud, созданный при помощи gridview
Имеется классический набор: 
модель, 
контроллер 
и представления

В таблице есть некоторое количество необходимых для отображения атрибутов и таблица не на всех экранах помещается (по ширине).
Как можно добавить полосу скроллинга на странице?
Или есть другое, возможно более удобное, решение?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837479/yii2-add-horizontal-scrollbar-in-gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте на вьюхе index класс `kartik\grid\GridView` для виджета GridView, вместо стандартного класса `yii\grid\GridView`

кажется это самый простой способ. без влезаний в css и лишней суеты

Comment: Этот вариант мне подошёл. Благодарю